# Is it possible to use pytest fixture that returns a list as parameters list of a test?

Tags: python, pytest

Consider the following code example, which is an abstraction of real code that I have:

```py
import os
import pytest

class Files:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file1 = "file1"
        self.file2 = "file2"
        self.file3 = "file3"
        self.file4 = "file4"
        self.file5 = "file5"

class MyRunner:
    def __init__(self, files_obj):
        self.files = files_obj

def get_files_to_copy(files_obj: Files):
    return [files_obj.file1, files_obj.file2, files_obj.file3]

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def runner():
    """ long time to run... """
    files_obj = Files()
    _runner = MyRunner(files_obj)
    return _runner

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def must_exist_files_list(runner):
    return get_files_to_copy(runner.files)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("file", must_exist_files_list)
def test_must_exist_files(file):
    assert os.path.exists(file), f"{file} does not exist"
```

My general idea is this: the `runner` fixture takes time to initialize, and is used for other tests (not displayed here). I need to use the `runner`'s `files` attribute to obtain a list of files for the `test_must_exist_files` test. I thought I can create a fixture that returns a list (`must_exist_files_list`) and use it as a parameters list for the aforementioned test, but it returns an error:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way to still do it similarly? Otherwise, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`must_exist_files_list` need to executed in tests collection time to get the parameters, but you can't call `fixture` directly. If it's good enough, you can use the `fixture` as test parameter, this will give you a single test with the list of files as parameter

```
def test_must_exist_files(must_exist_files_list):
    for file in must_exist_files_list:
        assert os.path.exists(file), f"{file} does not exist"
```

If you want to parametrize the test you can do it without `fixtures`, use a static variable to prevent running the slow code more than once

```
import os
import pytest


__runner = None


class Files:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file1 = "file1"
        self.file2 = "file2"
        self.file3 = "file3"
        self.file4 = "file4"
        self.file5 = "file5"


class MyRunner:
    def __init__(self, files_obj):
        self.files = files_obj


def runner():
    global __runner
    if not __runner:
        files_obj = Files()
        __runner = MyRunner(files_obj)
    return __runner


def get_files_to_copy(files_obj: Files):
    return [files_obj.file1, files_obj.file2, files_obj.file3]


def must_exist_files_list():
    return get_files_to_copy(runner().files)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("file", must_exist_files_list())
def test_must_exist_files(file):
    assert os.path.exists(file), f"{file} does not exist"
```

Comment: thanks. My goal is to create a separate test for each file provided by `must_exist_files_list` - so if, for example, file1 doesn't exist, we will still test file2 and file3

Comment: @noamgot I thought as much, but thought I would suggest it anyway. The second solution will give you that.